# Omnet++4.6 warning: ‘cLinkedList’ is deprecated

Tags: c++, c++11, simulation, simulator, omnet++

I have to simulate a WBAN network in Castalia and as Castalia is not compatible with the latest versions of Omnet++, but with Omnet++ 4.6 or below, so I downloaded that version. On installing and Omnet++ and doing 
    `make`
The following error comes on running the above command - 
    `warning: ‘cLinkedList’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]`

Should I ignore the message or can I still use Castalia?

Answer (score 2):

You can safely ignore those. Deprecation warnings are intentional to warn model developers that **later** OMNeT++ versions will remove that API, but the APIs are still functional.

On the side note: I just ported Castalia to OMNeT 5.4 / 6.0 and sent a pull request to the original author, however it was not yet merged to the main repo.

ported branch: https://github.com/rhornig/Castalia/commits/topic/omnetpp54-compatibility

pull request: https://github.com/boulis/Castalia/pull/16

Comment: Thanks a lot especially for the ported branch.

Comment: You are welcome. If an answer correctly solves your problem, please accept the answer so the question will be correctly categorized for further reference.

Comment: Thank you Rudi! As I wrote in Github, I am not sure when I'll find the time to test the merge but I want to acknowledge your contributions!